# why firefox prevent me from reseting password?

Tags: firefox, passwords

[image]

I forget my password and I want to reset ,but Firefox alert "Attempt limit exceeded"

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you've been resetting your password too often in a too short amount of time. Wait for x amount of time (couple of hours might do the trick) and try again.